# How do I make Sublime Text 2 prompt me before exit?

Tags: sublimetext2

There have been too many times where I have accidentally clicked the X on the top right window in Sublime Text 2. I then loose my undo/redo history.

Edit: I have tried to set hot_exit to false in default and user settings.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Look for **hot_exit** in Preferences.sublime-settings

```
// Exiting the application with hot_exit enabled will cause it to close
// immediately without prompting. Unsaved modifications and open files will
// be preserved and restored when next starting.
//
// Closing a window with an associated project will also close the window
// without prompting, preserving unsaved changes in the workspace file
// alongside the project.
"hot_exit": true,
```

and set it to false.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 sill exits with no prompt. I've done `"hot_exit": false,` in Preferences.Sublime-settings - Default and in User. What else can I try?

Comment: Strange, it doesn't on my machine...did you change it in Settings - Default or Settings - User?  Mine is set in Settings - User and prompts on exit.  Are you on a Mac or PC?  I know there are differences with how settings work between the OS's.  Also, try making the settings changes, then close Sublime.  Open up Sublime, open an existing file, make some text changes, then click the X of the window and it "should" prompt

Comment: Still no luck. I changed it on both Settings - Default and Settings - User. I am using Windows. I will try to restart my computer when I get a chance.

Comment: What build are you using? I'm on Version 2.0.1, Build 2217...strange because you shouldn't have to restart your computer for that change to take effect, just closing and starting up Sublime2 should be sufficient.

Comment: I am using the same build. Version 2.0.1, Build 2217

Comment: Sanity check: you're opening up a file, **making changes to that file**, then trying close it with the X, right?

Comment: Yes: Opening a file, making a change, saving it, then close with X. If I don't save it and close with X, it will prompt me to save but that isn't what I am looking for. BTW thanks for your prompt replies.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense then...if you save it, then hot_exit doesn't apply.  Also, you didn't mention saving it in your question.

Comment: Shucks, is there any way to get the prompt even if all files are saved?

Answer (score 0):

Install the plugin *Local History.*

> Every time you modify a file, a copy of the old contents is kept in
>   the local history.

Either do it through Package Control ([If you don't have it already, install it](https://sublime.wbond.net/))

[Or get it on Github](https://github.com/vishr/local-history)